# The content of UILabel is being truncated after rotation in Swift 4

Tags: swift, rotation, uilabel, sizetofit

I am using `AutoLayout`. I have a view with %10 width and 200 fixed height. I placed a `UILabel` into that view with 0 margins. Then I am rotating the `UILabel`, changing the content and calling `sizeToFit()` function. At the load of the controller the rotation works but the content is being truncated. After I did a button click on the controller, the `UILabel` is being enlarged and content is being fit.

What should I do to avoid this problem?

Note: I checked the width and height of the label's frame with debugging. After `sizeToFit()` the width and height of the frame changes as expected. However, the UI is not refreshing. I also tried `label.setNeedsLayout()` and `label.layoutIfNeeded()` but nothing changed.

For rotation I am using below extension:

```
extension UILabel {
    @IBInspectable
    var rotation: Int {
        get {
             return 0
        } set {
            let radians = CGFloat(CGFloat(Double.pi) * CGFloat(newValue) / CGFloat(180.0))
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After calling sizeToFit, try setting label.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height), height: max(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height))

Comment: It didn't work. The UI was not refreshed again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `view.layoutIfNeeded()` instead of `label.layoutIfNeeded()`